# Magnitude of force to keep stick in equilibrium

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics

**Problem statement**

A straight and homogenous stick with mass m is pressed against a wall with the force F. The stick is horizontal perpendicular against the wall. Given that the friction between the wall and the stick is μ, determine the horizontal component of F in order for the stick to not fall down.

**My thoughts**

Forces involved:

We have:
The gravitational force **mg** in the negative y-direction.
The normal force from the wall, **N**(negative x-dreiction). 
The friction force in the positive y-direction which is **f=μN** and
the force **F** which acts in the positive x-direction. Thus:

$$\sum F_{x}: F-N=0  \Rightarrow F=N \\
\sum F_{y}: mg-f=mg-\mu N=0  \Rightarrow N=F=\frac{mg}{\mu }$$

$$\boxed{F=\frac{mg}{\mu}}$$
[image: picture]

**Correct answer is $\boxed{F=\frac{mg}{2\mu}}$ **

Comment: Does $F_x$ morph into $F$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is in forgetting that the verictial component of force F holds up half the stick, so the friction force only needs to hold up the other half of the stick's weight, not the whole weight.

Answer (score 1):

Let the length of the stick be L. Consider moments about the **left-most** end of the stick.  With this choice of axis, neither the applied force F nor the normal reaction force from the wall on the stick contribute to the moments.

Gravity exerts a force of $m \times g$ downward at the centre of the stick, a distance $\frac{L}{2}$ from the left end.  This results in a **clockwise** moment on the stick,$ M_{CW}$; $$M_{CW}=m \times g \times \frac{L}{2}$$  Friction exerts a force $F_R$ upward on the right end of the stick, resulting in a counter-clock-wise moment, $M_{CCW}$;$$M_{CCW}=F_R \times L$$For no rotation, the two moments must cancel:$$F_R \times L=m \times g \times \frac{L}{2}$$So, after cancelling L$$F_R=\frac{m \times g}{2}=F_x \times \mu$$ $$F_x=\frac{m \times g}{2 \mu}$$